# How do I design an absent students request-approve workflow in Moodle?

Tags: plugins, moodle

Moodle version: - 3.9.1+      Theme:- Fordson    Theme version:- Moodle 3.9 Fordson v3.9 release 1.1 (2020061800)

I had a requirement to design a system for arranging missed courses/sessions for the absent students.

The requirement states that the absent student should send a request to the admin stating the reason for his absence for the course/session and the admin would go through the request and approve or deny the request based on the reason specified by the absent student in the request

How can I design such a system? Are there inbuilt features provided by Moodle for the absent students or are there any plugins or external features to be added to achieve this functionality? How do I approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several scenarios depending on how you manage the enrollments.

You have to think to the overall process, e.g. :

- Are your student already enrolled in the course they missed?
- Do you set an enroll period?

You can look if some enrollment plugins meet your needs on https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=22

Maybe this one can help you : https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_apply (I have not tried it)